# how to remove colon and white space in a string by php

Tags: php, regex

How can to remove colon's and white space's in a string by php.

.e.g: The Godfather: Part II

Comment: please use, For white space - >$removed_string = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ',$string_to_remove);

Comment: That works, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check This Code:

```
$demo_string =  "The Godfather: Part II";

$demo_string = str_replace(':', '', $demo_string);

$demo_string = str_replace(' ', '', $demo_string);
```

output : TheGodfatherPartII

Comment: this works, but I want to use preg_replace function. Thanks for your answer.